# How to use insert query where one of the value is a result of a subquery

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table such as table1 and table2. Below shows the following sample fields:

table1 : id, amount
table2 : id, total_amount

I want to insert a value to my table2 using an insert query. But the problem is I want one of the values of my insert query to be the result of a subquery inside an insert statement. For example:

```
INSERT INTO table2(id, total_amount) VALUES(111, (SELECT SUM(amount) from table1 WHERE id=1));
```

I knew that the above query is wrong. How can I do the query that can be able to insert to table2 
where one of the value to be inserted to table2 is the resulting query from my table1 as shown above?

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table2(id, total_amount) 
SELECT 111, SUM(amount) from table1 WHERE id=1
```

Comment: That worked. But what if I want to insert a data first on my table1 then get the SUM(amount) to be inserted on my table2? Is that possible ?

Comment: Then insert the data with an insert query and then run an update query on that record

Comment: Is that in just one query or with another query? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Since you want to make 2 steps out of it, then these are two queries. Actually I not quite get your request. maybe you should ask another detailed question if you don't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
 INSERT INTO table2(SELECT 111, SUM(amount) 
                    FROM table1 WHERE id=1);
```

Comment: How can I do this query? First execute this query : INSERT INTO table1(id, amount) VALUES ('',600) and then at the same time it inserts the SUM(amount) on table2 in just one query? Is that possible? If it is how ?

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
 $sql=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amount) as tot from table1 WHERE id=1")
 INSERT INTO table2(id, total_amount) VALUES(111,$sql['tot']);
```